# Add Page Break before adding a Split with Flowable

Tags: python, reportlab

I have an application that is using reportlab to build a document of tables. What I want to happen is when a flowable (in this case, always a `Table`) needs to split across pages, it should first add a page break. Thus, a Table should be allowed to split, but any table that is split should always start on a new page. There are multiple Tables in the same document, and if two can fit on the same page without splitting, there should not be a page break.

The closest I have gotten to this is to set `allowSplitting` to `False` when initializing the Document. However the issue is when a table exceeds the amount of space it has to fit, it will just fail. If instead of failing it will then wrap, this is what I am looking for.

For instance, this will fail with an error about not having enough space:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table_grid.pdf", pagesize=letter, allowSplitting=False)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []
data2 = []

data = [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
       ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
       ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
       ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]

for i in range(100):
  data2.append(['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE'])

t1 = Table(data)
t2 = Table(data2)

elements.append(t1)
elements.append(t2)
doc.build(elements)
```

The first table (`t1`) will fit fine, however `t2` does not. If the `allowSplitting` is left off, it will fit everything in the doc, however `t1` and `t2` are on the same page. Because `t2` is longer than one page, I would like it to add a page break before it starts, and then to split on the following pages where needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to make use of the document height and table height to calculate the correct placement of  `PageBreak()` elements. Document height can be obtained from the `SimpleDocTemplate` object and the table height can be calculated with the `wrap()` method.

The example below inserts a `PageBreak()` if the available height is less than table height. It then recalculates the available height for the next table.

```py
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, PageBreak

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table_grid.pdf", pagesize=letter)

# Create multiple tables of various lengths.
tables = []
for rows in [10, 10, 30, 50, 30, 10]:
    data = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] for _ in range(rows)]
    tables.append(Table(data, style=[('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 2, (0, 0, 0))]))

# Insert PageBreak() elements at appropriate positions.
elements = []
available_height = doc.height
for table in tables:
    table_height = table.wrap(0, available_height)[1]
    if available_height < table_height:
        elements.extend([PageBreak(), table])
        if table_height < doc.height:
            available_height = doc.height - table_height
        else:
            available_height = table_height % doc.height
    else:
        elements.append(table)
        available_height = available_height - table_height

doc.build(elements)
```